# Meaning of Stationarity

Tags: time-series, econometrics

If I have a time series that is completely non-stationary, that is, there is no way I can make it stationary (cannot see a deterministic trend and so on...), does it mean that I cannot make any prediction based exclusively on this time series?

Shortly:

Non-stationarity $\Rightarrow$ no prediction possible ?

Comment: how do you know it isn't stationary? You seem to have also recently posted this: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/35202/predict-the-behavior-of-a-time-series-pl-trading-desk

Comment: By visual inspection. Is it true that Non-stationarity ⇒ no prediction possible ?

Comment: There are some predictions that are possible. For example: 5. That's a prediction. You probably mean something else, though.

Comment: Did you try ARIMA mideling using differencing or seasonal differencing.  Trends do not have to be deterministic.